# issues with deQueue and table view cells

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with two different types of table view cells. When item.type = Course, I want the imageView in the table view cell to be a different width/height. However, what's happening is that as the cells are drawn, there's confusion. The images don't stay that height and take on the height for the other table view cell where type != Course. How can I fix this?

For example, when type = Course, imageView should be height = 212. However, what's happening, is that some images in that row are 212 while the other images are height = 120 (which should happen when type != Course).

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! LearningItemCollectionViewCell

    self.dataSource?.getData(cell: self)
    
    let items = self.items
    let item = items?[indexPath.row]
    
    if item != nil {
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item?.image as! String), placeholderImage: nil)
        cell.label.text = item?.title
    }
    
    if item?.type == "Course" {
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 212, height: 120)
        cell.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 130, width: 212, height: 20)
        cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    } else {
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 110, height: 165)
        cell.label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 175, width: 212, height: 15)
        cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    }
```

Comment: You should use different reuse identifiers for cells of different types

Comment: as @EugeneDudnyk mentioned, collectionview cells are reused.
you need to create like this.

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell\(indexPath.row)", for: indexPath) as! LearningItemCollectionViewCell